# When creating a package for Composer, how do you load dependencies?

Tags: php, composer-php, dependency-management

I've made packages for NPM and I know the drill there. You simply list your dependencies and then `require()` them. Node searches `node_modules`, finds the package, loads it and you're good to go.

How does that work in PHP, though? My dependency is [PoParser](https://packagist.org/packages/sepia/po-parser). I know I can just do:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

But when I publish my package, I wouldn't publish the third party dependency code, right? *My* package should only contain *my* code. At least that's the case with NPM.

So if I don't have that `vendor` folder when I publish my thing. How would I require my dependency? In Node, `require()` does that hard work. **How would I do it here?**

Here's my folder structure, if that helps:

```
vendor
    /composer
        ...
    /sepia
        /po-parser
            ...
            /src
                /Sepia
                ...
                // dependency classes
                ...
            ...
    autoload.php
composer.json
composer.lock
MyThing.class.php
Other.class.php
```

Answer (score 3):

Composer will handle that for you. Put your dependencies inside the `composer.json` file and when you require your project it will download the dependencies too.

Take a look at this tutorial: https://dev.to/ahmedkhan/smart-guide-on-creating-a-complete-php-package-using-composer